# Is it possible to send ListViewItem over socket TCP?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, send, listviewitem

Im making a file manager (Server-Client application) so i can mess with remote computer files
im using listview to watch the remote files 
Is there anyway possible to send a ListViewItem over a TCP Socket ? or i have to send information as a string and split them?

sorry for bad english.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: The client already knows how to make a ListViewItem.  All it needs is its *content*.

Comment: @HansPassant that's true .. my point that im asking how would i send the listviewitem instead of sending its contect .. name,text,tag ..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP socket is an endpoint for TCP protocol. TCP protocol transmits any binary data you might want to transmit. It is up to you to serialize your structures in a form that you can transmit over the wire.

There are several ways to serialize classes in .NET, such as binary serialization, XML serialization, and many third party libraries as well as manually.

`ListViewItem` explicitly supports binary serialization by implementing ISerializable interface. Examples how to use it can be found [here](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/29/149009.aspx) and [here](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2011/10/17/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-listview-data.aspx):

Comment: it may work as an idea but kinda complicated .. it looks if sent the info as string much easier